# Using Tab key to add a row in QTablewidget

Tags: pyside2, qtablewidget

I am developing a recipe application using a QTableWidget to add the ingredients for a recipe.  I use a button to add a row to insert a new ingredient.  This works well but like many existing applications I would like to use the tab key to add a new row when the last column in the last row has the focus.  I presume I must identify the tab key pressed and which column and row has the focus but I am not clear on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to subclass the table widget and implement the [`closeEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#closeEditor) function, which is called whenever a delegate signals that the editor is going to be closed, and is proposing the next action to do after closing.
Using the tab key, the `EditNextItem` hint is used, so it's enough to check for that flag, ensure if the current index is the last column of the last row, and then add a row *before* calling the base implementation method:

```py
class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def closeEditor(self, editor, hint):
        if hint == QtWidgets.QAbstractItemDelegate.EditNextItem:
            current = self.currentIndex()
            if (current.row() == self.rowCount() - 1 and 
                current.column() == self.columnCount() - 1):
                    self.insertRow(self.rowCount())
        super().closeEditor(editor, hint)
```

Comment: Thank-you for input.  I think I understand but needs a little study.  I am very weak on delegates.  One question,  why is the super() function called at the end of the closeEditor function overwrite?

Comment: @Liamdale the above code uses the default delegate of the table widget. The base implementation of `closeEditor` tries to start editing on the *next* possible cell, if you don't create the new row *before* that, it clearly cannot begin a new editing in the next row, because it doesn't exist yet.